# rsk private key encrypt - Error value parameter should be a number of string

Tags: javascript, encryption, ethers.js, rsk

I m trying to save my private key in a keystore v3 json format but when I try to encrypt it using the following methods:

```
myNewAccount.encrypt('########')
```

```
rsk.accounts.encrypt('the-private-key', '########')
```

They both give the following error:
`Uncaught Error: value parameter should be a number or string.`

Trying a slightly different approach,

```
rsk.accounts.encrypt('the-private-key', '########')
```

and I get a different error
`Uncaught Error: options.n should be number and has value of 2048, 4096, 8192 or 16384`

I even tried passing options as third argument to the encrypt function but the same error:

```
rsk3.accounts.encrypt('the-private-key', '#######',  { kdf: 'pbkdf2', n: 4096, salt, iv, uuid })
```

error -> `Uncaught Error: value parameter should be a number or string`

What am I doing wrong?
Here is how I create and use the account :

```
const account = rsk.accounts.create(rsk.utils.randomHex(32).toString('hex'))
rsk.accounts.wallet.add(account)
```

Comment: are you using rsk3.js? that has been deprecated, use web3.js or ethers.js instead.

Comment: Use: (1) [`new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-constructor), (2) followed by [`Wallet.encrypt(password)`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-encrypt). If you want to generate a new private key at random instead of using one that you already have, you can use [`ethers.Wallet.createRandom()`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-createRandom) instead for step (1).

Comment: Oh ok, good to know, so you mean everything is here should be ignored: https://developers.rsk.co/libraries/rsk3js/docs/rsk3/ ?

Comment: It worked with ethers, thanks

Comment: Great to hear that the ethers.js solution worked. Perhaps I'll expand the comment into a full answer. Also sorry that the docs are out of date - I'll put a deprecation notice up on that page that you have linked - thanks for bringing it to attention!

Comment: as promised, expanded into a full answer below --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73794841/194982

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use an **existing private key**:

(1) `new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)`

Reference: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-constructor

(2) `Wallet.encrypt(password)`

Reference: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-encrypt

```js
// assuming you already have values set for `privateKey` and `password`

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey); // (1)
const encryptedWalletJson = await wallet.encrypt(password); // (2)
```

If you wish to generate a **new private key**:

(1) `ethers.Wallet.createRandom()`

Reference: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-createRandom

(2) `Wallet.encrypt(password)`

Reference: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/signer/-%23-Wallet-encrypt

```js
// assuming you already have a value for `password`

const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom(); // (1)
const encryptedWalletJson = await wallet.encrypt(password); // (2)
```